# JSON reference parsing in Go

Tags: json, go, reference

I have such `json` file:

```
{
  "types": {
      "controller": {
        "base": {
          "speed": 1024,
          "n_core": 1
        }
      }
  },

  "Server1": {
      "type": {"$ref": "#/types/controller/base"},
      "name": "Server1",
      "is_in_json": true
    },
}
```

It contains `$ref` key. From [here](https://tools.ietf.org/id/draft-pbryan-zyp-json-ref-03.html#rfc.section.3) :

> The "$ref" string value contains a URI [RFC3986], which identifies the
>   location of the JSON value being referenced. It is an error condition
>   if the string value does not conform to URI syntax rules. Any members
>   other than "$ref" in a JSON Reference object SHALL be ignored.

For parsing I need to write a struct with `json-tag` like this:

```
type Server struct {
    Type ??? `json:"???"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    IsInJson bool `json:"is_in_json"`
}
```

What should I write in place of `???` for referencing another structure?

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: You parse it like any other JSON, those are just strings.

Answer (score 3):

If the key is always `$ref` and that's the only key to be captured from the object, as seems to be the requirement from the documentation you cited, then you can make a type for it:

```
type TypeData struct {
    Ref string `json:"$ref"`
}
type Server struct {
    Type TypeData `json:"type"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    IsInJson bool `json:"is_in_json"`
}
```

If that's not the case, the easiest thing is probably to assign it to a `map[string]string` and then iterate through the map to process elements appropriately:

```
type Server struct {
    Type map[string]string `json:"type"`
    Name string `json:"name"`
    IsInJson bool `json:"is_in_json"`
}
```